# Renaming networking interface through systemd-networkd not working in upgraded Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, networking, systemd, ubuntu-18.04, systemd-networkd

In an Ubuntu 18.04 server, I was not able to rename network interfaces through proven config-management-applied `systemd-networkd` configuration working on all other servers.

The only difference I see between servers originally set-up by configuration management and this partially hand-petted machine is that the Ubuntu server has been upgraded from at least 14.04, maybe even 12.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Investigating `initrd` and comparing with a server that worked, two obvious differences appeared through upgrading Ubuntu:

1. `/lib/udev/rules.d/71-biosdevname.rules`

   This is an old-times relict of renaming network interfaces in Ubuntu. It has to be deleted.
2. `/etc/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules`

   This was set-up shadowing `/lib/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules`, which (among others) also applies configuration from `systemd-networkd`. It contains a message indicating some miss-interpreted setup as VM (actually, this is a bare metal server):

   ```
   # This machine is most likely a virtualized guest, where the old persistent
   # network interface mechanism (75-persistent-net-generator.rules) did not work.
   # This file disables /lib/systemd/network/99-default.link to avoid
   # changing network interface names on upgrade. Please read
   # /usr/share/doc/udev/README.Debian.gz about how to migrate to the currently
   # supported mechanism.
   ```

   This file also has to be deleted.

A final `update-initramfs -u && reboot` results in properly renamed network interfaces.